# OpenSTV on election page - unavailable anymore

Tags: bug, status-completed, election, broken-link

On [*election page*](https://stackoverflow.com/election) there is a block containing a short description of the process and it has "*OpenSTV*" mentioned:

[image]

However the link to *OpenSTV (http://www.openstv.org)* from that block brings you to the [*OpaVote*](http://www.opavote.com/openstv) website stating:

> OpenSTV has been merged into OpaVote

and

> ... we are no longer supporting OpenSTV

So wouldn't it be correct to update the election process description with the new product(brand) name and the new link to its' [homepage](http://www.opavote.com/) like it was before with *OpenSTV*?

Comment: Maybe they are still using the old product with an old version. Not sure if it is correct to say they use the newer version.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Surely possible they're using the old version. It's just the wording of the announcement makes you think there is no old product available, i.e. it was subscription based with $400/year and now they have a different pricing policy, so the old one clearly discontinued, and "*hope that OpaVote fulfills the needs of our former OpenSTV customers*", like there is no more OpenSTV customers etc.

Comment: That's considered a broken link, and a bug. (As far as I can tell)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This message [looks fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/election/1?tab=election) already:

> [image: OpaVote]

Link "OpaVote" refers directly to https://www.opavote.com/