# Modify message about voting data due to OpenSTV merging into OpaVote

Tags: bug, election, wording

Messages on [moderator election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election/1?tab=nomination) which showing for an anonymous:

> [image: anon]

or logged in user:

> [image: logged]

should be fixed to refer to "OpaVote" [which was early an "OpenSTV"](https://www.opavote.com/openstv).

Related bug report already fixed [OpenSTV on election page - unavailable anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287087/339911)